# Why is Vim adding asterisks to my .css file?

Tags: vim, css, macvim

I'm editing a .css file with Vim (MacVim, actually), and when I type `*` followed by a newline, it automatically adds another `*` at the beginning of the next line. What setting is this, and how can I control it?

Comment: @Ingo Karkat will surely have some ideas :)

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Yes, but Heptite was faster :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with Vim's attempt to be helpful with comments. You will notice it does the same thing if your file is C or C++.

For most file formats this isn't a problem, but with CSS it can get in the way due to the ability to use *-wildcards.  You should be able to just backspace over it.

There isn't a simple answer to your question unless you want to disable auto-formatting of comments entirely.  In which case, try this:

```
:set formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o
```

See:

```
:help 'formatoptions'
:help fo-table
:help 'comments'
```

Comment: You can shorten the set formatoptions to `set formatoptions-=cro` (or with the shortform of formatoptions `set fo-=cro`

Comment: Actually, I would strongly recommend against that. If for some reason the "cro" is not in exactly that order somewhere in the string, `:set formatoptions-=cro` will not remove it.

Comment: As a beginner, I think I'll just backspace over it for now. This is good to know, for future reference though.